# Sending a UDP message stream - listener hanging after first receive

Tags: debian, centos, udp

I'm attempting to use `nc` to send a stream of messages from one server to another using UDP. On the sending side, Centos 7.5, I'm doing the following:

```
for s in $( seq 1 20 )
do
    echo "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') Hello - ${s}" | nc -u <receiver-ip> <port_no>
    echo ${s}
    sleep 2
done
```

and on the listening side, a Debian 10 VM, I'm running this to listen for the messages:

```
nc -u -l -p <port-no>
```

I've checked the port is not being used and, in fact, when I run the sender, I can see the count being output every two seconds. However, on the receiving side, I initially receive the following:

```
2021-04-13 05:26:29 Hello 1
```

but after that, I don't receive anything else, even though `nc` doesn't terminate. Just to be clear, I'd ideally hope to see 20 of these messages on the receiver in line with what's being sent.

I'm sure the reason for this is trivial but I've read through man pages (BTW, the sender is running `Ncat 7.50` and the receiver is running `nc [v1.10-41.1]`) on each platform and can't, despite various attempts, get this to work.

Can anyone explain why this isn't happening?

Comment: I suggest to check with a network sniffer program (tcpdump, Wireshark) if the packets get sent and received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `nc`-listener receives the first packet, it calls connect() on the socket to permanently associate it with the remote endpoint (sender host:port) that it just saw. This allows `nc` to use its standard read() loop instead of the UDP-specific recvfrom().

However, every invocation of the `nc`-sender uses a new socket and therefore a different ephemeral source port. The receiving socket ignores the packets because it was explicitly "connected" to a different address.

To avoid this, you could use the `-p` option *on the sender* to always specify a fixed source port.

Alternatively, since you're basically trying to reinvent UDP-syslog, you should probably just use a syslog daemon (e.g. syslog-ng or rsyslogd) and configure it to send messages to a UDP receiver.

Comment: Thanks, the logic seems sensible but it didn't work. I added the `-p` flag at the sender side (i.e. `nc -u <receiver-ip> -p <port_no>` but the only difference was that _nothing_ was received rather than just the first send. I do get your point about `syslog`, though I was hoping to do this really to grow my understanding of `nc` and sending/receiving with UDP before moving to that.

Comment: You still need to specify the destination port, not _just_ the source port.

Comment: Super! I changed to `nc -u <receiver-ip> -p <port_no> <port_no>` and this worked fine. Many thanks!